# RoR 4 unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, strong-parameters

I am creating a sign up page for users and accounts. Each account will be accessible to multiple users, but only 1 user will be the account owner.

```
# account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end

# accounts_controller.rb
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.build_owner
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      env["warden"].set_user(@account.owner, scope: :user)
      env["warden"].set_user(@account, scope: :account)
      flash[:success] = "Your account has been successfully created."
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Sorry, your account could not be created."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:account_name, :subdomain, 
      {:owner => [:username, :password, :password_confirmation]})
    end

end
```

I have also tried ":owner_attributes" as the key for the nested attributes hash.

The sign up page is pretty straightforward:

```
# /views/accounts/new.html.erb
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<%= form_for(@account) do |account| %>
  <%= account.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= account.label :account_name %><br>
    <%= account.text_field :account_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= account.label :subdomain %><br>
    <%= account.text_field :subdomain %>
  </p>
  <%= account.fields_for @account.owner do |owner| %>
    <p>
      <%= owner.label :username %><br>
      <%= owner.text_field :username %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= owner.label :password %><br>
      <%= owner.password_field :password %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= owner.label :password_confirmation %><br>
      <%= owner.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <%= account.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When running tests on this code, the server output indicates that there is an unpermitted parameter "user", which causes the account creation to fail:

> Started GET "/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-10 14:41:26 +0000
>   Processing by AccountsController#new as HTML
>    Rendered accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (51.7ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 127ms (Views: 57.7ms | ActiveRecord: 31.2ms)
>   Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-10 14:41:26 +0000
>   Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "account"=>{"account_name"=>"Test Firm", "subdomain"=>"test", "user"=>{"username"=>"User1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}
>   Unpermitted parameter: user

For informational purposes, here is the test code that is being used:

```
RSpec.feature "Accounts", type: :feature do
  owner = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)

  scenario "creating an account" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign Up"
    fill_in "Account name", :with => "Test Firm"
    fill_in "Subdomain", :with => "test"
    fill_in "Username", :with => owner[:username]
    fill_in "Password", :with => owner[:password]
    fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => owner[:password_confirmation]
    click_button "Create Account"
    success_message = "Your account has been successfully created."
    expect(page).to have_content(success_message)
    expect(page).to have_content("Signed in as #{owner[:username].downcase}")
    expect(page.current_url).to eq("http://test.example.com/")
  end
end
```

I'm confused why a parameter of "user" is being sent (and rejected) since both the model and controller are using the "owner" name? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Why was the previous answer deleted? Also we do not need your test, at least I don't.

Comment: Not enough for a full answer, but I think it would be best (cleanest to read/understand) if you make an `owners` scope in the User model, perhaps where `account_id IS NOT NULL`. From there, it allows you to have `users_attributes`. You can ensure the user is an owner by seeing if it is included in the owners scope.

Comment: Evidently my mistake; I didn't realize that if I edited the question the answer previously provided would be deleted. The suggested answer was to override the default behavior of ActiveRecord by adding an `as: :owner` option to the belongs_to association of the Accounts model. Unfortunately `as:` is not a recognized option in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? And I do not think you editing the Q deleted a question. That comment was for the person who deleted it themselves (of which I did not catch the name).